# Unable to locate package -- when the /file/ is right in the directory (it's a .deb)

Tags: apt, package-management

Guys: I'm tearing my hair out on this problem. I have 2 .deb files ready to install, and when I do sudo apt-get install *.deb I get:

```
E: Unable to locate package discord-0.0.14.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'discord-0.0.14.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'discord-0.0.14.deb'
E: Unable to locate package XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb'
```

My ls -lah shows:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4.0K Mar 24 08:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root    root    4.0K Mar  2 20:57 ..
-rwxrwxr-x  1 kcredden kcredden  69M Mar 24 08:54 discord-0.0.14.deb
-rwxrwxr-x  1 kcredden kcredden  52M Mar 24 08:52 XnViewMP-linux-x64.deb
```

There was one fix that said some app wasn't installed, which I did and it fixed it then. But now I've got the same problem, so any help?

```
    NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Why are you doing apt get if you have the file already on your hard drive? The sudo apt-get update command is used to download package information from all configured sources. The sources often defined in /etc/apt/sources. ... So when you run update command, it downloads the package information from the Internet. It is useful to get info on an updated version of packages or their dependencies.

Comment: To help you with the install read this already answered question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt

Comment: If you're in the directory that the file is in, you can install it one of two ways:  `sudo apt install ./discord-0.0.14.deb` or `sudo dpkg -i discord-0.0.14.deb`.  Notice when using the `apt` command you put a `./` in front of the file so that `apt` knows you are using from the folder you are in.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `./` when referring to packages in the current directory when using `apt`.

Answer (score 0):

Terrance and David:

Thanks for the help. I finally managed to get them installed using:

sudo dpkg --force-depends -i /path/to/package.deb

Some of the command structure is somewhat new to me, which is one reason I goofed. But also I tried everything you pointed out in the answered question, David before I got that one that worked.

It seems U-20 still has some bugs needing worked out.

Comment: If a system has bugs, please report them (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) or be specific and provide the bug tracker IDs.  Bugs don't exist until they are reported. `apt-get` provides the clue in it's name, it 'gets' the packages from the internet (and doesn't install local files).  Be careful with using `--force-depends` or you'll find yourself back here with package problems (or crashing programs if ABI/APIs don't match up; what *dep-rules* help prevent)

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is the syntax used.** When no path is specified, `apt` assumes you are referring to a package name, not a file. Apt requires the full path to install a package from a deb file, even when the package is in the current directory. The path to the current directory is `./`

So, instead of this:

```
sudo apt install *.deb
```

you should use the full path:

```
sudo apt install ./*.deb
```

However, to avoid conflicting dependencies, you should update your package list before you begin like this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ./*.deb
```

---

**Additionally**, if you install using `dpkg -i package.deb` or `dpkg --force-depends -i package.deb`, you need to run the following command to install the necessary dependencies after installation.

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Just run the command as is and do not specify a file or a package name.

You see, the `--force-depends` flag simply returns dependency errors as warnings and does not download or install the necessary dependencies. `sudo apt -f install` uses the "fix" flag to actually fix those dependencies.